# R how to add column name as title

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
plots <- data %>% 
  select( contains("Pct")) %>%
  map(~ggplot(data, aes(y= . , x = Project_Name ,fill=Project_Name,)) +
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7) +
    theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank() , axis.text.x=element_blank() )+
    labs(title=names(.)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2"))

ggarrange(plotlist = plots,common.legend = TRUE)
```

using the above code, I am able to get the plot but not able to get the y-axis label, can i add the selected column names as y-axis label or the plot title (names(.)) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved by using `purrr::imap` instead of `map`.

Using `iris` as example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)
library(purrr)

plots <- iris %>% 
  select(contains("Petal")) %>%
  imap(~ggplot(iris, aes(y = .x , x = Species , fill=Species)) +
        geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7) +
        theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank() , axis.text.x=element_blank() )+
        labs(title=.y) +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2"))

ggarrange(plotlist = plots, common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]